# Anime where you become a wizard/witch if you survive being attacked by a monster

Tags: story-identification, anime

The main character lives with this older witch that trained him. He became one when he was little because you become a wizard if you live from an attack from a monster and then the older witch looked after him. The magic people are hated by people. Also there was a blonde girl whose personality changed from nice to well not nice.

There is two seasons for this anime.
the monsters name is nemesis

Comment: This is a nice overview but can you remember anything else that happened? Can you remember the details of the attack on the MC? How he came to live with the witch? Anything that happens after that? Any of the plot at all or what happens in specific episodes? How does the blonde girl fit into the story? If you remember anything else please [edit] those details into your question.

Comment: The setting would also be useful? Modern day? Standard village based fantasy period?

Comment: its a bit of both but the mc is from a standard village thing

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi Stack exchange! Please can you take the [tour] and look at [help]. It looks like you have a good answer, but please do [edit] in your extra details anyway. Things like when you watched this, and where you saw it can be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick Google search for "anime nemesis wizard witch" points to **[Radiant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_(manfra))**, a French comic series adapted as a two-season Anime.

Wikipedia plot summary:

> In the world of Pompo Hills, an race of monsters called Nemeses fall from the sky. These creatures contaminate everything they touch. People who survive their contact become cursed, but also gain the ability to wield the magic power known as "Fantasia", thus becoming Sorcerers. Seth, the protagonist of Radiant, is a 15-years old boy who has survived a Nemesis attack. He dreams of defeating all of the Nemeses and bringing peace between Sorcerers and the rest of humanity. To do so, he has to find the place where the Nemeses come from, the legendary Radiant, and destroy it. He and other sorcerers travel the region in search of Radiant whilst avoiding the Inquisition, an organization opposed to the Sorcerers.

The witch:

> Alma (アルマ, Aruma) - A woman who is an experienced Sorcerer and Nemesis Hunter. She survived the same Nemesis attack Seth survived from ten years ago, losing her right arm. She since raised Seth and teaches him on controlling his Sorcerer powers.

The blonde girl:

> Mélie (メリ, Meri) -A girl with a split personality, she later becomes friends with Seth.

Comment: oh yeah it is that lmfao thanks man